# Different Hyper-v Integration Services Versions

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to get a grasp on these different hyper-v integration services version numbers. If I go on the hyper-v host and check the registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization\GuestInstaller\Version

I see the following:

```
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Guest-Installer  -  6.3.9600.18398
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Guest-Installer-Resources-en-US  -  6.3.9600.16384
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Guest-Installer-Support  -  6.3.9600.16384
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Guest-Installer-Win5x-Package  -  6.3.9600.18398
Microsoft-Hyper-V-Guest-Installer-Win6x-Package  -  6.3.9600.18398
Microsoft-Windows-Wdf-WdfCoInstaller01009-vm  -  6.3.9600.16384
```

Now, I know that the Win5x, and Win6x packages are for 2012/2008 servers and if I run the powershell command:

```
Get-VM | ft Name, IntegrationServicesVersion
```

I'll see mainly 6.3.9600.16384 but, what Im expecting to see is 6.3.9600.18398 because I thought that was the highest version out now.

What am I missing in the understanding of tracking these hyper-v integration services version numbers?

Answer (score 1):

After you update your Hyper-V Server with the latest windows updates you will be able to deploy the "latest" integration services that is available to the Server.

Comment: I dont follow, the hyper-v hosts are updated up till November's latest updates but my understanding is hyper-v integration components were last updated in Julys update, and the servers certainly have been updated since then, and rebooted. When I check the host servers versions, it shows 6.3.9600.16384 and 6.3.9600.18398, as seen in my original post, and that is confusing me. I've manually updated some VMs by inserting the vmguest iso and am working to deploy it to all VMs soon. I'm just trying to better understand the different version numbers are if I should be looking at one over the other.

Comment: Interesting, and by manually updating the VM's the version number is updated? I have seen as I update security packs on a Hyper-V host has shown that I need to update integration services.  As far as the numbering scheme goes.  I'm not sure.

Comment: Its weird, if I manually update the VM with inserting vmguest.iso I get the version 6.3.9600.18398. If I let it check and install through SCCM I see it remains at 6.3.9600.16384.